# Android linear layout difficulties

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I have a portrait xml layout file which contains a text-box which rests onto of an ImageView. This was done using a vertical linear layout. The trouble is, I have created a landscape xml layout file, but I don't know how to insert a text box above the ImageView in this particular layout file. For some reason i'm having trouble.

To summarize, I want to replicate the style I had in my portrait xml (with regards to the text-box and ImageView relationship). Pictures below should clarify exactly what I mean. Icons are covered in gray on purpose, but you get the general idea.

My Landscape xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!-- This relative layout will center EVERYTHING within it. Do not touch this functionality. -->
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/relative_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <com.edmodo.cropper.CropImageView
            xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/CropImageView"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center" >
        </com.edmodo.cropper.CropImageView>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".12"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                tools:ignore="UselessParent" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/button1of3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/button1_description"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_rotate"
                    android:visibility="invisible"
                    tools:ignore="Suspicious0dp" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/button2of3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/button3_description"
                    android:padding="2dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_camera" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/button3of3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/button4_description"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_feed" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: Landscape layout]
[image: Portrait layout]

Comment: Why you go for two layouts?? you can maintain single layout for both portrait and landscape..

Comment: @Lokesh I know, but I had an issue with my portrait xml (once I turned my phone into landscape mode). So that's not an option i'm afraid. thanks for the suggestion though  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wrap your CropImageView inside a layout, for example, a LinearLayout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/relative_layout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/test"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight=".12"
            android:text="Test" />

        <com.edmodo.cropper.CropImageView
            xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/CropImageView"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".88"
            android:gravity="center" >
        </com.edmodo.cropper.CropImageView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".12"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            tools:ignore="UselessParent" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/button1of3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:contentDescription="@string/button1_description"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_action_rotate"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                tools:ignore="Suspicious0dp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/button2of3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:contentDescription="@string/button3_description"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_action_camera" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/button3of3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:contentDescription="@string/button4_description"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_action_feed" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick. I tried the same thing, but I didn't use weights-and I was wondering why my textView wouldn't show up! lol...saved me some frustration.  :)